# Efficiently read Firestore's document reference field contents

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, nosql, foreign-keys, document-database

I'm trying out Firestore with this data model:

- a collection of pokemon, where a pokemon is `{ name: string, move?: Ref<move> }`
- collection of moves, where a move is `{ name: string }`

I have data entry for 2 pokemon one of which has the move with name "*growl*" while the other has no move field.

I would like to read the pokemon collection from a Next client and build an array with two items of the shape `{ name: string, move?: { name: string } }`

My initial code looks something like this:

```
import firebase from "./{configfilepath}"

...

const db = getFirestore(firebase)
const pokemonRef = collection(db, "pokemon")
const pokemonQuery = query(pokemonRef)
const pokemonSnap = await getDocs(pokemonQuery)

...

const pokemon = []
pokemonSnap.forEach(async (doc) => {
  const docData = doc.data()
  const moveRef = docData.move
  const moveSnap = moveRef ? await getDoc(moveRef) : undefined
  const moveData = moveSnap ? moveSnap.data() : undefined

  pokemon.push({
    id: doc.id,
    name: docData.name,
    move: moveData,
  })
})
```

When I execute this code I obtain an array with only one entry, which is the one the skips the call to the awaited calls.

So the issue is that the `.forEach` method of Firestore's `QuerySnapshot` is not awaiting for the promises to resolve, but I'm not seeing another built-in method that can deal with async operations.

So I moved to something that handles the promises outside of the Firestore's `forEach`:

```
...

const pokemonRaw = []

pokemonSnap.forEach((doc) => {
  pokemonRaw.push({
    id: doc.id,
    data: doc.data()
  })
})

const pokemon = await Promise.all(pokemonRaw.map(async (rawData) => {
  const moveRef = rawData.data.move
  const moveSnap = moveRef ? await getDoc(moveRef) : undefined
  const moveData = moveSnap ? moveSnap.data() : undefined

  return {
    id: rawData.id,
    name: rawData.data.name,
    move: moveData,
  }
}))
```

Honestly, this seems a bit too complex for relatively simple read operation involving referenced fields, so my question is: **is there a more succinct and idiomatic way to access referenced fields when reading Firestore records from a client** and **would I be better off forgetting about referenced fields when modeling data with Firestore**?

Comment: 1) No. 2) That's entirely a matter of your preferences and product requirements.

Comment: in the question I choose not to mention I was using autogenerated ids, while it might have been useful to use a string containing a document name, since that might be useful for both a view in the client and for querying additional details if required (cfr. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56395480/when-to-duplicate-data-in-nosql#comment99401711_56396939)

Answer (score 1):

Since part the original question was a bit vague and requested an opinionated answer, the only really correct answer is that "*it depends*".

Still, I think it's worth mentioning that with Firestore it's common enough to avoid the issue of handling layers of relations when rendering a simple view of available fields by **providing a human-readable string instead of a relational field**.

For the move with name "*growl*", I can store it in a pokemon record with the string with value "*growl*", **which is what I want the user to see in the details of a pokemon**.

Then if the user is interested in knowing more details about the move **I can fire a different query for moves that match the value** "*growl*" in their name field.

Alternatively, **you could also choose to use the value "*growl*" as the name of the record itself** which would remove the need to read the value of any contained field, with the (possibly useful) constraint of having a unique record.

While this constrains a bit what you can fetch with a single query for your pokemon, I think **it gives enough information for the user to receive a useful and interactable ui**.